# Is it possible to use COUNT and INNER JOIN in one query like this

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay, I know, that it's possible to use count and inner join in a query, but I don't know if what I want is possible.

I got this:

```
    $queryA = "SELECT 
        answer.a_id,
        answer.answer,
        answer.timestamp,
        answer.m_id,
        member.m_id,
        member.first_name,
        member.middle_name,
        member.last_name,
        member.picture
            FROM
        answers AS answer
            INNER JOIN
        members AS member ON answer.m_id = member.m_id
            WHERE q_id = '".$q_id."'
            ORDER BY a_id DESC
    ";
    $resultA = $con->query($queryA) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($rowA = $resultA->fetch_assoc()) {
       ...my code...
    }
```

I'm trying to make a bit of a forum and this is giving me the answer and the member who wrote the answer.
I have made a script, that makes it possible to upvote the answer (AJAX). When someone upvotes an answer a record is created in another table like this:

[image]

This is how I controle who upvote which answer and when.

I could simply make another query for EACH answer, that checks if a record, with the members id, answer id and question id already exists. This means that if there is 50 answers, that would be another 50 calls from the database. I don't want that.
Is it possible to somehow include this in the query above?

Afterwards I would like to be able to make something like this:

```
if($rowA['counted'] > 0) {
    ...show this..
}
else {
    ... or this
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add your tables (answer & member) on SQLFiddle ?
So we will be able to run the same query as you and have an online demo withe sample data. http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find if a specific member has upvoted, add to SELECT:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes v WHERE
       v.m_id = [current_member.id] AND 
       v.a_id = answer.a_id AND
       v.q_id = q_id) as has_voted
```

find the number of member-unspecific votes: same as above, but leave the m_id out:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes v WHERE
       v.a_id = answer.a_id AND
       v.q_id = q_id) as count_voted
```